# How to integrate ISAM and MobileFirst Foundation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, isam

I need use ISAM for sso, Do you have any detail instruction for that?
I have read information in KnowledgeCenter, redbooks, but I still not know how to do the integration. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034222

Take a look at some of the integration docs written for the version you are running.